# Update Android app with HttpClient to OKHttp3

Tags: java, android, httpclient, okhttp

I'm trying to upgrade some Java code to fit in with an android app.
The code references the depreciated the Apache http module which Android no longer supports since Marshmellow.

I need to complete a POST of the XML code.

I'm new to connections and OKHttp3. Is there a way I can achieve a similar result with using OKHttp3?

```
private static String SubmitXml(String Xml, String Url) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare the POST request
    HttpPost pxpayRequest = new HttpPost(Url);
    pxpayRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(Xml));

    // Execute the request and extract the response
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = client.execute(pxpayRequest, responseHandler);

    return responseBody;
}
```

I've searched the web but most OKHttp3 articles I've seen reference sending JSON data or something similar. Nothing with XML.